# WCF REST Service Hosted in Azure Service WebRole: AccessControlService?

Tags: wcf, rest, azure, wif, accesscontrolservice

Im working in a project providing rest services on the azure pllatform. 
The service is consumed by a iPhone client, this is one of the big reasons for choosing the rest approach.

We want to secure the wcf services with AccessControlService(ACS), using identity providers like google and liveId. I have now spent more than a day researching and trying to get it to work, and the lack off information makes me wonder if it even is possible.
I have among other things tried configuring the role with the Add STS Reference tool from Windows Identity Foundation(WIF).

So i guess my question is: 
Is it possible to secure the service using AccessControlService(ACS)?

Also if this is not possible, do anyone know any way of achieving the same functionality i.e. 
ACS securing the WCF service (oAuth not an option) users logging in with live gmail or other well known identity provider.

Dont have web.config file or others on this pc but can get them later if anyone wants to have a look.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research it doesn't seem to be a way to use ACS in this manner at the moment. During the researching it occured to us that oAuth directly to the different providers is a better choice as it lets us access the users data(If the user lets us :) ). 
What we decided to do was to implement our own stuff communicating using the oAuth protocol with the providers we liked(facebook, google).

Here is info on how to do it:
[Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/),
[Google](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Labs version of ACS today.

You can find example code at: 
http://acs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Samples&referringTitle=Home

Comment: I´m using the labs version. The samples covering services rely on either manually adding credentials in the ACS for obtaining a token, or using a certificate. What we want to do is use identity providers like facebook or google to obtain a token. Is this possible?